# Where to put my files for ifstream and fstream

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl, ifstream

My application returns 0x3 and crashes. I found that it maybe that fstream cannot open the file. Where it should be? I mean, same folder as the application.exe or elsewhere? I am using Code::Blocks

EDIT

Code::Blocks is setting the working directory with the cb runner

```
GLuint sh;
int meret;
char * s;
std::ifstream fa1 ("vertex.vert",std::ios_base::binary);

fa1.seekg(0, fa1.end);
meret = fa1.tellg();
fa1.seekg(0, fa1.beg);
fa1.read(s,meret);
fa1.close();
//sh = glCreateShader(st);
const char * s1[1] = {s};
std::cout << s;
```

Comment: it should be in _the working directory_.. But don't rely on relative paths, use full paths?

Comment: But if I move the application or give it to someone?

Comment: Then the proper way is to add a way to configure the location of the file. A less versatile way is to put the file in the same directory as your exe, and in your code figure out the path where your exe is, then calculate the file's path from it.

Comment: @P0W what would you like to know?

Comment: @SimonG It is there..

Comment: Are you certain it's the failure to open a file that's causing the problem? Post some code that illustrates the issue.

Comment: I agree with SteveL: file not found is very frequently exit code 2, not 3.

Comment: @SteveL Added some code. I am not sure by the wa. Now I am currently tring to get that `char *  s` output to stdout but it wont.

Comment: `s` is not initialized! you can use `malloc` to allocate some memory to which the file contents will be read.

Comment: Facepalm. You are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is this line:

```
fa1.read(s,meret);
```

Since you've not allocated any space for the array `s`, attempting to write to it will be bad.

```
s = new char[ meret ];
```

Just before the `read` might fix your issue, as long as the file isn't too big...
NB: you don't need to manually close the `ifstream` object - it will close when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Just tried this before you posted! I use only char not new char. Now it works! Thanks SteveL,  Kilian Rosbach!